# R: How to return the smallest distances between cities?

Tags: r

I have a large matrix a part of which looks something like this:

```
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]    [,5]
[1,]      0      3     10      7       6
[2,]      3      0      9      4      11
[3,]     10      9      0      8      15
[4,]      7      4      8      0      16
[5,]      6     11     15     16       0
```

Each column/row represents a city, and the corresponding number tells you the distances between them.

I want to find three cities that are closest to each city.

I wrote

```
apply(Matrix,1,order)
```

to find the order, but not sure how to extract the closest cities from this.

So for each city, say called 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I want it to return

```
[1] 1, 2, 5
[2] 1, 2, 4
[3] 2, 3, 4
[4] 1, 2, 4
[5] 1, 2, 5
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right to use `apply` with `order`. The command `apply(mat, 1, order)` returns the results column-wise. You can extract the first three values with `[seq(3), ]`. The function `t` transposes the resulting matrix.

```
t(apply(mat, 1, order)[seq(3), ])

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    5
[2,]    2    1    4
[3,]    3    4    2
[4,]    4    2    1
[5,]    5    1    2
```

Comment: I think I need to add a bit more description. I'll add it to above, please help me if you can. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
pairwisecities <- melt(apply(mdat,1,order))
```

will give you pairwise rankings, you can then `subset` on `pairwisecities` for `value <= 3`

`apply(mdat,1,rank)` will give you the ranking.

Comment: I think I need to add a bit more description. I added it to above, please help me if you can. :)